# new_time returning time in 12hrs format

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, timezone

In my function I want to convert time from GMT to BST.
My query is like below

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(NEW_TIME ((TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 20/24 + 21/1440),
                        'GMT',
                        'BST'),
               'HH24:MI'
       )
FROM DUAL;
```

Its returning me '9:21' instead of '21:21'.
Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions105.htm#SQLRF00671), BST refers to Bering Standard Time, and not British Summer Time as you are expecting.
[Bering Standard Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bering_Standard_Time) is at UTC-11, so the result that you get is as expected.

NEW_TIME function can accept only limited timezones specified in the above documentation.If you want to convert GMT to British Summer Time,
you should probably use 'Europe/London' timezone.

```
select (cast(your_date as timestamp) at time zone 'GMT') at time zone 'Europe/London'
from dual;
```

So your query will be,

```
SQL> select 
    (cast((TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 20/24 + 21/1440) as timestamp) at time zone 'GMT') at time zone 'Europe/London',
    to_char((cast((TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 20/24 + 21/1440) as timestamp) at time zone 'GMT') at time zone 'Europe/London','hh24:mi')
from dual;

(CAST((TRUNC(SYSDATE)+20/24+21/1440)ASTIMESTAMP)ATTIMEZONE'GMT')ATTIMEZONE' TO_CH
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- -----
14-MAY-14 09.21.00.000000 PM EUROPE/LONDON                                  21:21
```